# How to find normal vector direction on a time-evolving curve with curvature and torsion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, 3d, curvature

I have a question about computing normal vector direction to a time-evolving curve please.

The **normal vector direction** for a curve in 3D space with curvature k and zero torsion can be found by rotating the current velocity vector, for instance [1,1,0], by 90 degrees around the z-axis for every time step:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 * cos (Pi/2) - 1 * sin (Pi/2) \\
    1 * sin (Pi/2) + 1 * cos (Pi/2) \\
    0
    \end{matrix}
$$

This is because the normal always lies on the same xy-plane, and is unique after a consistent rotation angle of 90 degrees.

But when the torsion is non-zero, the z-component of velocity will grow over time as the bi-normal vector points it into the z-direction and cause the z-component of velocity to be non-zero over time. The velocity is no longer planar on the xy-plane.

**What should the equivalent rotation formula be to find the correct normal vector direction now**, for example when the velocity vector is currently [1,1,1]:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    ? \\
    ? \\
    ?
    \end{matrix}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard about Serret-Frenet differential system ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for answering! yes i have read about the Serret-Frenet formula, but I am having difficulty translating it to the rotation based system i am using. This is to be simulated discretely using 3D graphics, so I don't have the complete analytic parametrized description of the curve over all path history t.